# flutter-sending widgets as a list and fitting them inside the container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to send a list of widgets inside a container. Just like in the example, there is a green container and I want to send a custom widgets inside.

What I want is that if the list of containers does not fit into the container it is sent to, only the elements that fit are displayed on the screen.

```
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: allPokes.length,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        allPokes[index].name.toString(),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Row(
                        children: List.generate(
                            (allPokes[index].type!.length), (i) {
                          List<Type?> allTypes = allPokes[index].type!;
                          return typeContainer(allTypes[i].toString());
                        }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Row`, use `Wrap` and wrap it with container which have specific height, like this:

```
Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                height: 40,
                child: Wrap(
                  children: List.generate(
                        (allPokes[index].type!.length), (i) {
                      List<Type?> allTypes = allPokes[index].type!;
                      return typeContainer(allTypes[i].toString());
                    }),
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Comment: that is good but i dont want this. 
What I want is, for example, if the third widget of the widget list won't fit in that container, the first 2 widgets should be display. Is there anything that can be done for this?

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. but this solution required specific height. It means you only can use this solution if you set height for your typeContainer widget.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know If I Understood What u want exactly,
But I think Replacing Your `Row` With `Wrap` Will Fix Your Problem,
Replay if this is not what you need

```
 return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
  child: GridView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: 10,
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'name',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Wrap(
                children: List.generate(10, (i) {
                  return TextButton(child: Text('name'), onPressed: () {});
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

[image]